# register a sound to a button click

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to press the button and have the sound play on every press. as of right now it only plays after it finishes playing the first time, not on every press.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer boost = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.boost);
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!boost.isPlaying())
            {
                boost = new MediaPlayer();
            }
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResource(R.raw.boost);
                boost.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                boost.prepare();
                boost.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: just stop current play, and start new one on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if (!boost.isPlaying())
                        {
                            boost= new MediaPlayer();
                        }
                        try {
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.boost);

                           boost.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                            boost.prepare();
                            boost.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: there are two ways to do it,weather put the file in your assests folder and simply pass the name or do it like this `res.openRawResourceFd(boost);`

Comment: I dont follow. is it even necessary to use AssetFileDescriptor or could I just use prepare into start

Comment: what do you mean prepare into start?

Comment: the boost.prepare(); and boost.start(); would using those 2 alone work?

Comment: I have a new problem now. Im getting some errors with NullPointerException. I imagine I need to move my mp3 file

Comment: I am still getting errors. I'm probably just stupid but I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I have the mp3 file in the raw folder it is being referenced everywhere needed. and I am still getting null pointer

Comment: follow my instructions create an assests folder then copy paste your sound file

Comment: the if statement is now giving errors. because boost is final

Comment: remove the final,give me +1 if i helped you

Comment: boost is not accessible from an inner class and res must be an expression. I appreciate you bearing with me

Comment: did you remove the final?and the final of the button too

Comment: yes. 'boost cannot be accessed from within inner class. must be declared final' and res 'qualifier must be an expression'

Comment: please paste all your class code in your question and let me see

Comment: resubmitted it in the question

Comment: remove final from your button